# Page source does not reflect what browser displays

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a webpage with the following:

```
<input id="ColourPicker" type="text" value="000000" />
<asp:Label ID="ColourChosen" runat="server" Text="000000" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

These are bound to a jPicker:

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {
    $('#ColourPicker').jPicker(
      {
        images: { clientPath: 'Scripts/images/' },
        window: { position: { x: '25', y: '0' }, expandable: true }
      },
    function(color) {
      var all = color.val('all');
      document.getElementById('ColourChosen').innerHTML = all.hex;
    });
  });
```

When I select a colour in jPicker and click OK the browser displays:

[image: ColourPicker]

The box on the left is ColourPicker and the label on the right is ColourChosen.

When I view the Page Source I see this:

```
<input id="ColourPicker" type="text" value="000000" />
<span id="ColourChosen">000000</span>
```

I have some code-behind of this:

```
protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var l = new List<Borg.PlotColurs> {new Borg.PlotColurs()};
l[0].PlotColour = ColourChosen.Text;
Borg.BulkInsert(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["utilConnectionString"].ConnectionString, "PlotColours", l);
ListView2.DataBind();
}
```

I want to see ColourChosen.Text to equal f41313, but it always equals 000000.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page source you are looking at is the source that was downloaded from the server. All the editions later made through Javascript (including the plugin) are not reflected in the page source.

To see your changes you should use either FireBug in Firefox, Chrome devtools in Chrome or the Internet Explorer developer tools.

Comment: Aha, excellent, I didn't know that. I have just seen it in Firebug and the value of ColourChosen does change. Thanks.